# C++ timer calling a member function of a class

Tags: c++, timer, callback

I have a Timer class for calling a function periodically, but so far I have only been able to operate it on free functions. Now the need arose that I should be able to execute a member function of a class using this timer.

```
class Timer
{
    void (*func)();
    bool running;

public:
    Timer();
    ~Timer();

    void start();
    void stop();
    void setCallback(void (*func)());

private:
    void run();
};

// Sets the function which is to be called periodically.
void Timer::setCallback(void (*func)())
{
    this->func = func;
}

// Starts the timer with a non-blocking call that returns immediately.
// The timer and the callback function are executed on a detached thread.
// Execution stops when stop() is called.
void Timer::start()
{
    std::thread th(&Timer::run, this);
    th.detach();
}

// Stops the timer.
void Timer::stop()
{
    running = false;
}

// Private function executing the periodic callback.
void Timer::run()
{
    // The general strategy of the timer is:
    // 1. Call the callback function.
    // 2. Measure how long it took.
    // 3. Sleep the remaining time of the period.

    running = true;
    struct timespec now, then, period;
    while (running)
    {
        // Time before the function call.
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &then);

        // Call the provided callback function.
        if (func != 0)
            (*func)();

        // Time after the function call.
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &now);

        // Determine the remaining time that needs to be slept.
        period.tv_sec = 100/1000; // 100 ms period
        period.tv_nsec = (ms % 1000) * 1000000 - 100000;
        period.tv_sec -= (now.tv_sec - then.tv_sec);
        period.tv_nsec -= (now.tv_nsec - then.tv_nsec);

        // Sleep for the remaining time.
        clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, 0, &period, NULL);
    }
}

void tick()
{
    // something very useful
}

int main ()
{
    Timer timer;
    timer.setCallback(tick);
    timer.start();
}
```

How can I accomplish registering a member function as a callback for the timer?

I like how a member function is passed to a thread for execution

```
std::thread ft(&Timer::run, this);
```

and would like to adopt the same syntax for setting up a callback for the timer like so:

```
void setCallback(&SomeClass::someMember, &instanceOfSomeClass);
```

but I can't figure out how to write this function. I would prefer to abstain from macros, typedefs, lambdas, std::function and std::bind if possible in order to keep the code more accessible to beginners like myself. It is perfectly sufficient if the callback function takes no arguments and returns void, but unfortunately it cannot be static.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: switch to using a `std::function<void()>` as the member of the class.  then you can take in any function type and store it in there.

Comment: On a side note: I would not suggest `detach`ing the `run` thread. You should save the thread in a class member so that you can `join` it properly in `stop()` and the timer's destructor. The way you have it right now, the thread can still access the `timer` object after the object has been destroyed. Also, using the system clock is not a good way to implement a timer since there is no way to interrupt the sleep. Consider using a `condition_variable` instead, that way the thread can wake up and exit more quickly when `stop()` is called. And you should `stop()` the timer in the destructor.

Comment: NathanOliver, could you give me a syntax example of how you mean that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `std::function<void()>` would be the best choice, it is definitely possible to do it without it (however, I would recommend using it unless you have good reason not to).

To use `std::function`, just replace your instances of `void (*)()` with `std::function<void()>`, and `#include <functional>` in your file, e.g.

```cpp
class Timer
{
private:
  std::function<void()> func;
  ...
};

void Timer::setCallback(std::function<void()> func)
{
    this->func = func;
}
```

If you want to avoid using `std::function`, then some extra work is needed.

Since your timer callback is a `void()`, you're basically stuck with free functions. However, if you embellish this with a singular `void *context` parameter, you can express 'closures' which can capture extra arguments. Think about `void *context` being roughly equivalent to `this`. So, your code would change ever so slightly to...

```cpp
class Timer
{
private:
  void *context;
  void (*func)(void *context);
  ...

public:
  void setCallback(void (*func)(void *), void *context);
};

void Timer::setCallback(void (*func)(), void *context)
{
    this->func    = func;
    this->context = context;
}
```

The idea here is that now, you can smuggle in a pointer to your `func`, reinterpret it as some object, and use that to influence the behaviour of your callback. In the case of a member function call, you could pass your object as the `context`, and have your `func` call a particular member function on it. You could wrap this all up in a template to make the call a bit simpler:

```cpp
// NOTE: There might be ambiguity between the two overloads
template <typename Class>
void setCallback(void Class::(*fn)(), Class *self)
{
  // I'm being lazy and blindly allocating here. You can figure out how you'd like to deal with this
  struct closure { Class *self; void Class::(*fn)() fn; }; 
  setCallback(
    [](void *context)
    {
      closure *ctx = reinterpret_cast<closure *>(context);
      (ctx->self)->*(ctx->fn)();
    },
    new closure { fn, self },
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Works like a charm. The std::function approach does make more sense.

Comment: Just for completeness, you would then need to call timer.setCallback(std::bind(&YourObj::someFunc, instanceOfYourObj)); to register a member function as a callback.